# Not able to invoke RESTFul service from AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, jsonp

Hope some can help me here.

I have a restful service which i am invoking from AngularJs application but am getting error like below. I am able to invoke the service from browser or any other rest client and able to get the results. Please review below code and help.

My controller

```
scotchApp.controller('newLogicalTeamController', function($scope,$http,$routeParams) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.applicationSel = $routeParams.Appl_Sel;
    console.log(1111);
    $http.jsonp("http://localhost:8080/PortalService/rest/GetDataService?callback=callback")
        .success(function(response) {
            console.log(1);
            $scope.ApplicationList = response;
            console.log(response);
        }).error(function(){
            console.log(2);
        });
});
```

My service

```
 @GET
    @JSONP(queryParam="callback")
    @Produces({"application/x-javascript"})
    public List<LogicalTeam>  getLogicalTeams()
    {

        System.out.println("1");
        con = PostgreSQLJDBC.getConnection();
        try {
            st  = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(QUERY_GET_LOGICAL_TEAM);
            System.out.println("2");
            while(rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println("3");
                LogicalTeam team = new LogicalTeam();
                team.setIntTeamId(rs.getInt(1));
                team.setStrTeamName(rs.getString(2));
                team.setStrSubBizGrp(rs.getString(3));
                team.setStrBizGrp(rs.getString(4));
                teamList.add(team);
            }

            return teamList;

            //return new JSONWithPadding(teamList,callback);


        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;

    }
```

Output when i hit service from browser.

```
callback([{"intTeamId":300,"strBizGrp":"100","strSubBizGrp":"201","strTeamName":"New Business"}])
```

Console log

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: callback is not defined
```

I also tried return type as JSONPadding but no luck. when i use $http.get am getting error like below. So i switched to $http.jsonp. I am not sure i am doing right thing to invoke rest service

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/PMPortalService/rest/GetDataService?callback=callback. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your callback needs to be "JSON_CALLBACK" literally.

Try

```
$http.jsonp("http://localhost:8080/PMPortalService/rest/GetDataService?callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
```